# Eloquent Multitable query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, twig

I trying to create a search function in php with Slim and Eloquent 5.1, but i have a problem to get the results from the database. 
This are my tables

```
Listing Table
  id |  title | description | price |  size  |etc...
-----|--------|-------------|-------|--------|-------
  1  | list1  | some text   | 500   |   50   |
  2  | list2  | some text   | 700   |   80   |
  3  | list3  | some text   | 350   |  120   |

Listings Option Table
  id |  id_listing | opt_name    | opt_value
-----|-------------|-------------|----------
  1  |      1      | rooms       |    3
  2  |      1      | baths       |    4
  3  |      2      | rooms       |    8
  4  |      3      | baths       |    1
  5  |      3      | rooms       |    6

Listings Images Table
  id |  id_listing | file_name   
-----|-------------|-------------
  1  |      1      | file_1.png       
  2  |      1      | file_2.png       
  1  |      2      | file_3.png      
  2  |      3      | file_4.png
```

Now i found a way to get all the results with all they options with

```
listado = $app->listing->with(['options'],['imgs'])->get();
```

My classes

```
//Listing Class

class Listing extends Eloquent{
  protected $table = 'listings';


  public function options(){
    return $this->hasMany('Casas\Listing\ListingOption', 'id_listing', 'id');
  }

  public function imgs(){
    return $this->hasMany('Casas\Listing\ListingImg', 'id_listing');
  }

}

// ListingOption class

class ListingOption extends Eloquent{
  protected $table = 'listings_options';

  public function listings()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('Casas\Listing\Listing', 'id_listing');
  }

}

// ListingImg Class
class ListingImg extends Eloquent{
  protected $table = 'listings_imgs';

  public function listings()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('Casas\Listing\Listing', 'id_listing');
  }

}
```

but i cannot find a way to filter the query the way i want to. I tried many thing.

**Example: I want to get all the listings that have price less than 600 and have more than 2 rooms.**

So that be listing id 1 and 3

If anyone can help create this query i'll appreciate that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want want to use is `whereHas`.

> When accessing the records for a model, you may wish to limit your results based on the existence of a relationship

```
$result = $app->listing->with('options', 'imgs')
    ->whereHas('options', function ($query) {
        $query->where('opt_value', '>', 2)
            ->where('opt_name', 'room');
    })
    ->where('price', '<', 600)->get();
```

So what we are doing here is, eager loading **options** and **imgs** tables and fetching only the **listings** that have at least one option where **opt_value** is bigger than two and **opt_name** is **room**.

You can find more in info about querying relationships in [here](http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)

Comment: Thanks a lot i've tweaked that a bit and got it working exactly how i wanted to. Thanks a lot @FabioAntunes

Comment: @abonive I'm glad that I helped you out!

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
$result = $app->listing->with(
    ['options' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('opt_value', '>', 2);
        }
    ], 
    ['imgs'])->where('price', '<', 600)->get();
```

The last, outer `where` should be assigned to `listing`. The inner `where`, passed in a callback, should be assigned to `options` directly.

Take a look at the [**docs**](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) (the "Constraining Eager Loads" section).

Comment: I tried that i but first, with this where in options i don't know if it's looking at option rooms or baths and its returning both. And it returns listings that have no options at all too.

Comment: Sounds like you need to limit the result even more. You can simply chain other `->where()` clauses to get exactly what you need.

Comment: I tried something like this
        `$listado = $app->listing->with(
     ['options' => function ($query) {
         $query->where('opt_name', 'rooms')->where('value', '>', 2);
         }
     ], 
     ['imgs'])->where('price', '<', 600)->get();`

but is not working

Comment: Change the `with(['relation'=>functon($q){}])` to  `whereHas('relation',functon($q){})` statements more info [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)